# Intuitive Explanation that Brachistochrones (Time-Minimizing Curves) have a Constant Change of Angle per Time

Tags: curves, plane-curves

In a [3 Blue 1 Brown video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cld0p3a43fU) (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cld0p3a43fU), 3b1b gave the following challenge:

> Give an **intuitive reason** why **time-minimizing curves** going from one point to another under the effect of gravity look like straight lines in the t-$\theta$ space, which maps each time to the change in angle of the curve.

Which is equivalent to saying that the if the Brachistochrone curve is modelled as $f(x)$, then the function that measures the angle of the tangent line of $f$ at $x$, which we will call $g(x)=\tan^{-1}f'(x)$, then the function $g'(x)$ looks like a line, that is, $g''(x)$ is a constant. (Intuitively, $g(x)=0$.)

Did anyone make any discoveries concerning this? A scroll through the comments didn't reveal anything either.

Comment: Asking people in MSE to watch Youtube videos isn't always getting a lot of attention. Suggest that you formulate a self-contained question using math jax. The link to the video can still be used as a reference.

Comment: I think I said "Give an intuitive reason why time-minimizing curves look like straight lines in the t- space." I'm gonna be more specific

Comment: Donenenenenene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can view the sliding motion as a non-linear pendulum of variable length and variable center of oscillation on an instantaneous pivot I..

$$ L \ddot\theta + g \sin \theta=0$$

Angle $\theta $ is made to vertical line and $\phi= \theta-\pi/2 $ is to made to horizontal by path  tangent.

Qualitatively at least

$$-y \ddot \phi+ g \cos \phi=0$$

Acceleration or the path curvature $1/R_1$  must be proportional to $\cos \phi/ y= 1/R_2$ which is in fact a geometrical property of the cycloid:

$$\frac{R_2}{R_1}=\frac{1}{2}= \frac{PC}{PI}$$

The locus of I is another cycloid. The answer could be improved after any specific aspects in the question from the video are addressed.

[image]